# How to show or hide a div tag under each checkbox when checked or unchecked in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, web-deployment

I want to display a div element under each checkbox when it is checked and hide it when checkbox is unchecked.

Below is my html:

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="days">Please select the days:</label>
    <div class="checkbox-inline" *ngFor="let day of days">
       <label>
         <input
         class="form-check-input"
         type="checkbox"
         [value]="day"
         name="{{day}}"
         id="{{day}}"   
         (change)="onDayChecked($event.target.checked)"
         required>
         {{day}}
        </label>
        <div *ngIf="showTime">
             <!--Display this under each checked box and hide if unchecked-->
        </div>
     </div>
   </label>
<div>
```

My ts file:

```html
isDayChecked: boolean;
  showTime: boolean=false;
  onDayChecked(isdaychecked: boolean) {
    this.isDayChecked=isdaychecked;
    this.showTime=false;
    this.days.forEach(
      day=>{
        if(this.isDayChecked){
          this.showTime=true;
        }
      }
    )
  }
```

Using this code when I check one box, the div tag under each day is being displayed. But I want to display the div tag under the checked boxes only.

Can anyone please let me know how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[(ngModel)]` to bind the data from the template to the typescript file and once the binding variable is true, show the data.

```
1. Template

 <div class="row">
    <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="condition">
    <div *ngIf="condition===true">
      <div class="alert alert-success">
        You Can See Me!
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

2. TS File
  condition : boolean = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Now your variables **isDayChecked** and **showTime** are global variables to the component, so when you check a checkbox and call **onDayChecked** function, you change the value to variables isDayChecked and showTime only one time (not for every day in the array). My recommendation is to convert the array days to an array of objects.

Suggested structure array:

```
days = [
   {
     dayName: 'name',
     showTime: false
   },
   {
     dayName: 'other day',
     showTime: true
   }
];
```

HTML file:

```
   <div class="form-group">
          <label for="days">Please select the days:</label>
            <div class="checkbox-inline" *ngFor="let day of days">
               <label>
                 <input
                 class="form-check-input"
                 type="checkbox"
                 [value]="day.dayName"
                 name="{{day.dayName}}"
                 id="{{day.dayName}}"   
                 (change)="onDayChecked($event.target.checked, day)"
                 required>
                 {{day.dayName}}
                </label>
                <div *ngIf="day.showTime">
                     <!--Display this under each checked box and hide if unchecked-->
                </div>
             </div>
        </div>
```

.ts file:

Delete isDayChecked and showTime variables.

```
onDayChecked(isDayChecked: boolean, day: any) {
    day.showTime = isDayChecked;
}
```